# Graph / Google API, is it possible get code without browser log-in?

Tags: google-api, microsoft-graph-api

I'm developing an app where automation is the main component. It setups by showing the QR code in front of the camera and then everything is set up automatically. I wonder if it's possible to get a "code" by passing the credentials with a POST request or something similar without the user needing to interact. Let's assume the user gave consent already on a computer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method to Get access on behalf of a user:

[image]

Please refer this document for further information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user